# Actual parameters in Python lambda expressions

Tags: python

I am having difficulties understanding a concept in Python, particularly related to the use of lambda functions. I will refer to the example used in the official Python documentation.

Here is the example: ([found here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions))

```
>>> pairs = [(1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three'), (4, 'four')]
>>> pairs.sort(key=lambda pair: pair[1])
>>> pairs
[(4, 'four'), (1, 'one'), (3, 'three'), (2, 'two')]
```

I understand the functionality of lambda itself, being an anonymous function. But what I don't understand is how it exactly accepts arguments as opposed to the normal callable function: like `add(x,y)` , `x` and `y` here are actual parameters sent as input to `add()` function, while formal parameters seen in the function definition can be like:

```
def add(val1, val2):
    return val1 + val2
```

But in the first example above, what is the actual parameter sent to lambda? when `pair` is the formal parameter (which can take any name of course.)

Comment: `"what is the actual parameter sent to lambda? when pair is the formal parameter"` This question isn't clear at all. What is "actual" parameter"?
 what is "formal" parameter? You already seem to understand that `pair` is every tuple in `pairs`.

Comment: A lambda function is *exactly* the same as a standalone function in terms of parameters. Your lambda is exactly the same as `def myfunc(pair): return pair[1]`.

Comment: There is no such thing as a separate `lambda` *function*; a `lambda` *expression* is simply an expression whose value is a `function` object, the same type of object created by the `def` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lambda pair: pair[1]` is exactly equivalent to a function definition like the following:

```
def lambda_equivalent (pair):
    return pair[1]
```

So `pair` is the parameter the anonymous lambda function accepts. It only has that one parameter.

The function is then passed as the argument to the `key` parameter of the `list.sort` function. So it again would be equivalent to the following:

```
pairs.sort(key=lambda_equivalent)
```

What `list.sort` then does is call that `key` function for every item to determine the *actual value* list items should be sorted by. So `list.sort` will eventually call `key((1, 'one'))` and `key((2, 'two'))`, etc., so the list item—the tuple—is the parameter that is passed to the key function. In case of your lambda, this would be `pair`.

Comment: Thanks. How `list.sort` method works (as a member of pairs) answers the question perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Even though `lambda` function definitions have a different form as opposed to normal functions, they're still called exactly the same way:

```
>>> add = lambda x, y: x + y
>>> add(1, 2)
3
>>> def add(x, y):
...     return x + y
... 
>>> add(1, 2)
3
```

In your example `lambda pair: pair[1]` is equivalent to:

```
def sort_by_pair(pair):
    return pair[1]
```

The resulting function is passed to `list.sort`. `list.sort` expects this value to be a callable that accepts a single argument. Behind the scenes `list.sort` still calls the function that was given for `key` **for each element in the list**. So each time the `key` function is called, it's passed a single element from the list:

```
>>> def sort_by_pair(pair):
...     print('Called with argument:', pair)
...     return pair[1]
... 
>>> 
>>> pairs = [(1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three'), (4, 'four')]
>>> pairs.sort(key=sort_by_pair)
Called with argument: (1, 'one')
Called with argument: (2, 'two')
Called with argument: (3, 'three')
Called with argument: (4, 'four')
>>> pairs
[(4, 'four'), (1, 'one'), (3, 'three'), (2, 'two')]
```

Notice if you make the `lambda` accept no arguments when passed to `list.sort`, an error is raised:

```
>>> pairs = [(1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three'), (4, 'four')]
>>> pairs.sort(key=lambda: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Answer (score 0):

In the above example as you given if we took the simplest one like that:
`dict = {1:2, 2:1}` then for sorting we'll do`sorted(l.items(), key=lambda (x,y):y)` or `sorted(l.items(), key=lambda (x):x[1])` in the second solution x contains list of elemnts like x[0] and x[1] which is key and value of each each dict elements.

Now on your case treat **pair** like a list which contains  **pair[0]** and **pair[1]** so the actual paramenter sent to lambda is the second element of tuple (which is an element of list) like  *[tuple1, tuple2, tuple3]*